# Specific area of the laptop heats up unusually

Tags: hardware-failure, overheating, intel-graphics

[image]

This is the image of the laptop that I own [HP Pavilion DV4-2126tx].

Towards the left of the laptop is a `RJ-45` socket where I connect the internet cable and close to it is the graphics card, hard drive and the slot for remote control.
For the past couple of days I have observed that the area of the keyboard near the `RJ45` socket and HDD heats up more than usual.

I have the laptop raised about half a centimeter above the desk.

The HDD temp stays at `40C` and the CPU at `50C` while the aforementioned area heats up. I do not know what is causing the heating but to dissipate the heat, I ejected the remote control and voila, the area cooled down.

How much heating is observed ? More than what is considered lukewarm.

**I would like to know what is causing the heating.**

### Misc

*Workload while heating is observed:* Nominal workload like reading a pdf file. The portion heats up in 15 mins of laptop start

*Other observed things:* Today, the PC, out of its own accord, turned off `Windows Aero` while it was in charging mode. I also observed that when this happened, the power policy had also moved from `Balanced` to .. NOTHING. The radio button disappeared. Do I link this to a failing GPU ? (currently it is operating on `Generic PnP Monitor on Intel Graphics Media Accelerator HD` **Is it failing?**

*OS*: Windows 7 Home Premium 32 bit

Comment: Isnt this the location of physical fan ? if so, then it is usually normal that the fan place is a little hotter

Comment: @ilansch the fan is on the back side of the laptop, where the screen and the body get joined

Comment: When was the last time you cleaned dust out of the fans, vents and heat-sinks?

Comment: @techie007 never :/